# How to bypass invalid SSL certificate errors in httpClient.executeMethod(httpPost) in servlet

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

How do I bypass invalid SSL certificate errors? Secure connection is no needed! I looked same answers but no result. I tryed to use TrustManager but then have error in httpClient.getParams().setContentCharset(CLIENT_CHARSET).
Heres servlet sample code:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { response.setContentType("text/html; charset=windows-1251");
    java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    List listDoc=null;
    String dateDoc=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(java.util.Calendar.getInstance ().getTime());
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03:00"));
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    String yesterday=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(calendar.getTime());

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     httpClient.getParams().setContentCharset(CLIENT_CHARSET);
     if (request.getParameter("d")!=null)
     {
         yesterday=request.getParameter("d");
     }
     if (request.getParameter("k")!=null)
     {
         String id=request.getParameter("k");
         bean.setKontrNamesList(oracle.connect("Select * from NTR where konturl is not null and NTR.`LOAD`=1 and krid="+id+"","MS"));
            listDoc=oracle.connect("Select * from NTR where konturl is not null and NTR.`LOAD`=1 and krid="+id+"","MS");

     }
     else
     {
    bean.setKontrNamesList(oracle.connect("Select * from NTR where konturl is not null and NTR.`LOAD`=1","MS"));
    listDoc=oracle.connect("Select * from NTR where konturl is not null and NTR.`LOAD`=1","MS");
     } 

     bean.setTypeNamesList(oracle.connect("Select * from typedoc","KIR"));
    for (int i=0;i<listDoc.size();i++)
    {
        List ter1 = (List) listDoc.get(i);

        String req_string=ter1.get(1)+";"+ter1.get(2);
        System.out.println(ter1.get(1)+";"+ter1.get(2));
        PostMethod httpPost = new PostMethod(URI);
        httpPost.getParams().setContentCharset(CLIENT_CHARSET);
        String name=base.replace(ter1.get(0).toString(),"\"","");
        System.out.println(name+"  "+req_string);
        if (ter1.size()>3&&ter1.get(3)!=null&&ter1.get(3).toString().equals("1"))
        { 
         httpPost.addParameter(name,req_string);            
         httpPost.addParameter("dateDoc",yesterday);

         if (ter1.size()>7&&ter1.get(9)!=null&&ter1.get(9).toString().equals("1"))
             httpPost.addParameter("T12","T12");
         httpClient.executeMethod(httpPost);    
            }
    }       



}
```

**UPDATE:**
Problem solved by update Java 1.6 to Java 1.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

Comment: @BrettOkken there is depricated solution